# Arc length of a 3D set of points

Tags: computational-geometry

Suppose I have a data set of 3D coordinates that form a pretty continuous path in space. I would like to measure the total arc length (or path length) of the entire system. At this point the coordinates are not connected. 
[image: Here's what I have so far]

Comment: Are the points in the correct order or do you need to order them first?

Comment: The points are in the correct order!

Comment: then all you need is `ArcLength@Line@pts`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The very best method**

[Bob Hanlon, in a comment below, solved the issue with what I further call an "ingenious method"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128567/arc-length-of-a-3d-set-of-points/128569?noredirect=1#comment347804_128569):

```
Total[RegionMeasure@*Line /@ (list[[#]] & /@ FindCurvePath[list])]
```

working with `list` of points forming a nicely behaving (e.g., no loops) curve in 2D or 3D.

---

**Straightforward approach**

```
data = Table[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}];

ListPointPlot3D @ data
```

[image]

The "exact" result in this case is

```
NIntegrate[Norm @ D[{x, x^2, x^3}, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

> 1.86302

A rough estimate might be the sum of distances between consecutive pairs of points:

```
Total @ (EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1])
```

> 1.86301

or in a compact form

```
RegionMeasure @ Line[data] (* thanks: Szabolcs *)
```

> 1.86301

or

```
ArcLength @ Line @ data (* thanks: JasonB *)
```

> 1.86301

---

**Overcoming some caveats**

The above assumes that the points are ordered in the "correct" way. Simple `Sort` won't work when the curve "runs back", and the points are not in the correct order. As an illustration let's take

```
f[x_] := -1 + 4 x - 4 x^2 + x^3

data2 = Table[{f[x], x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 3, 0.01}];

ListPointPlot3D @ data2
```

[image]

```
NIntegrate[Norm @ D[{f[x], x^2, x^3}, x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

> 30.0472

and

```
RegionMeasure @ Line[data2]
```

> 30.0472

or

```
ArcLength @ Line @ data2
```

> 30.0472

coincide nicely. Here's what happens when the points are in random order:

```
data3 = RandomSample @ data2;

RegionMeasure @ Line[data3]
```

> 2747.76

and `Sort` fails miserably:

```
RegionMeasure @ Line[Sort@data3]
```

> 1548.66

I define a set

```
data4 = data3;
```

in which I find the "smallest" point:

```
start = Min /@ Transpose@data4
```

> {-1., 0., 0.}

which for future use I'll make a copy of:

```
s0 = {start};
```

and now I seek point after point the point nearest to the preceding:

```
data5 = s0~Join~Reap[Do[
      data4 = Complement[data4, {start}]; 
      Sow[start = Nearest[data4, start][[1]]];, {i, 300}
      ]
     ][[2, 1]];
(* I guess this could be done in a different way, possibly with NestList, or with some other ingenious method *)
```

which gives

```
data5 == data2
```

> True

and of course

```
RegionMeasure @ Line[data5]
```

> 30.0472

---

Another approach can employ `FindShortestTour` (thanks: JulienKluge and Rahul):

```
start = Min /@ Transpose@data3
end = Max /@ Transpose@data3

t1 = Max @ Position[data3, start]
t2 = Max @ Position[data3, end]

First @ FindShortestTour[data3, t1, t2]
```

> 30.0472

---

**Wrapping things up in a single function**

```
curveLength[data_] := Block[{data4 = data, start, s0, data5},
  start = Min /@ Transpose@data4;
  s0 = {start};
  data5 = s0~Join~Reap[Do[
       data4 = Complement[data4, {start}]; 
       Sow[start = Nearest[data4, start][[1]]];, {i, 
        Length @ data4 - 1}
       ]
      ][[2, 1]];
  RegionMeasure @ Line[data5]
  ]

curveLength[data]
```

> 1.86301

---

**ISSUE**

None of the above approaches (except for the `FindCurvePath` one) will work with curves like this:

[image]

because the `start`ing point was *found* as a point with its coordinates smallest in the `data` set, which is not the case now. One can of course provide the `start`ing point manually, and then the length of the curve can be still obtained.

Comment: Lazy man's way: `RegionMeasure@Line[data]`.

Comment: For the last Part: you could have also used FindShortestTour

Comment: @JulienKluge I thought about that, but `RegionMeasure@Line@data3[[FindShortestTour[data3][[2]]]]` gives `58.6909`; one needs first to find the `start`ing point (which is on position 196 in this case) and swap it with the first element in the list, which appears not to be so trivial. If you can come up with an idea I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Ohh okay. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If you know the indices of the starting and ending points you can use `FindShortestTour[data, i, j]`. If not, `FindShortestTour[data]` returns a cycle, from which deleting the longest edge should give you the desired path.

Comment: @JulienKluge There's more to it: `FindShortestTour` gives the length of a cycle, i.e. from start to end + from end to start; it doesn't matter which point is first. It gives `58.6909`, the distance between start and end is `28.6182`; their difference is `30.0727`, which is pretty close to the result of `30.0472` (I'm a bitt concerned by the discrepancy though).

Comment: @JulienKluge Btw: you can swap any two points at positions `a` and `b` in a `list` with `list[[{a, b}]] = list[[{b, a}]]`.

Comment: `Total[RegionMeasure@*Line /@ (data3[[#]] & /@ FindCurvePath[data3])]`

Comment: "working with **any** list of points forming a curve" - it works in a lot of cases, but certainly not all of them: `pts = RandomSample[First[Cases[Normal[ParametricPlot[{Sin[3 t], Sin[8 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]], Line[l_] :> l, Infinity]]];`

Comment: @BobHanlon That's what I called an "ingenious method" in my post.