# How to reparametrize a curve by arclength using Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions, vector-calculus

There are some formulas in Differential Geometry that require a curve to be parametrized by arc length. Suppose we have a curve $\alpha(t)$, given by

```
alpha[t_] := {f1[t], f2[t], f3[t]}.
```

Now, my question is: if I wanted to reparametrize by arc length the procedure would be:

1. Compute $\alpha'(t)$ and integrate $s(t) = \int_0^t |\alpha'(\tau)|^2 \mathrm{\tau}$
2. Invert $s(t)$ to obtain $t = t(s)$.
3. Define a new curve $\beta(s) = \alpha(t(s))$.

How could I do this with mathematica? There are procedures there like inverting which I'm unsure how would be used.

On the other hand since this is a quite common use case I believe there might be some easier way to do with Mathematica.

How could I do this? How can I get a curve and reparametrize by arc length with Mathematica?

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128567/arc-length-of-a-3d-set-of-points)

Comment: Would you be satisfied with a numerical solution, i.e. representing $t(s)$ as an`InterpolatingFunction`? Or do you need an analytic form for $t(s)$?

Comment: "There are some formulas in Differential Geometry that require a curve to be parametrized by arc length." - not necessarily; those formulae can in most cases be modified for general parameters. Note that most integrals do not have neat closed forms, much less their inverses, so you'll be using `NDSolve[]` most of the time, as alluded by Jason's comment. See [this related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454).

Answer (score 1):

I post this to illustrate some functions, e.g. `ArcLength`and `Interpolation` that may be helpful. In the following a "three-petalled rose" is used to show 2 parametrizations (polar:green, arclength: red). The arc length parametrization is approximated by interpolation

```
r[t_] := RotationMatrix[Pi/4, {1, 0, 0}].{Cos[t] Sin[3 t], 
   Sin[t] Sin[3 t], 0}
arc[t_] := ArcLength[r[u], {u, 0, t}];
if[n_, step_] := 
 Interpolation[Table[{arc[j], r[j][[n]]}, {j, 0, 2 Pi, step}]]
{xs, ys, zs} = if[#, 0.1] & /@ Range[3];
ra[u_] := {xs[u], ys[u], zs[u]};
anim = Table[Show[ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
    Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[ra[p]]}]],
   {p, 0, 0.95 arc[2 Pi], 0.05}];
anim2 = Table[Show[ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
    Graphics3D[{Green, PointSize[0.04], Point[r[p]]}]],
   {p, 0, 2 Pi, 0.05}];
```

Polar parametrization:

[image]

Arclength parametrization:

[image]

It is not perfect. Comparing 'speeds' along curve:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Sqrt[D[r[t], t].D[r[t], t]]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
Plot[Evaluate[Sqrt[D[ra[t], t].D[ra[t], t]]], {t, 0, 0.95 arc[2 Pi]}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}]
```

[image]